# DPS payment gateway integration

Tags: asp-classic, payment-gateway

I need to integrate DPS payment gateway in a site. Can anyone provide me the script to implemnent in the site. The site is built in classic ASP.

Comment: Dude... a "gimme teh codez" question, and you never accept answers. Not a good way to get answers to your questions.

Comment: And in your question you don't specify what/who the "DPS gateway" is - there is one named that in this country and they provide very good examples of connecting to them. How can people answer if you give very few details?

Answer (score 0):

Most gateway providers will give you the code or at least a very thorough guide to show you what you should be doing. If yours doesn't, perhaps look for one of the many that do help with integration.

As you don't go into specifics, I don't see how anybody can give you more of an answer than that.